# Solve assigns variable outside of loop, but fails inside For loop

Tags: equation-solving

This code works when it is not in a for loop, but as soon as I put it in a loop it stops assigning the variable q.

```
fdotf[x_, y_, z_,w_] = (4*x - 2*y + 3*z - 5*w)^2 + (3*x + 3*y + 5*z - 
  8*w)^2 + (-6*x - 1*y + 4*z + 3*w)^2 + (-4*x + 2*y - 3*z + 5*w)^2;
ClearAll[q]
gradfdotf = Grad[fdotf[x, y, z, w], {x, y, z, w}]
gradfdotf = Simplify[gradfdotf];
gradfdotf = gradfdotf /. {x -> x0[[1]], y -> x0[[2]], z -> x0[[3]],w -> x0[[4]]};
x1 = x0 - q*gradfdotf;
Solve[D[fdotf[x1[[1]], x1[[2]], x1[[3]], x1[[4]]], q] == 0, q];
q2 = q /. %[[1]];
q = q2;(**learning rate **)
x0 = x0 - q*gradfdotf;
N[x0]
```

The above code works, but if I put it in a loop all of the sudden it stops!If I try to print q now, it just prints q as opposed to the solution of Solve.

```
    ClearAll[q]
x0 = {5, 5, 5, 5};
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, Print[N[x0]];
ClearAll[q, q2];
gradfdotf = Grad[fdotf[x, y, z, w], {x, y, z, w}];
gradfdotf = Simplify[gradfdotf];
gradfdotf =   gradfdotf /. {x -> x0[[1]], y -> x0[[2]], z -> x0[[3]], 
w -> x0[[4]]};
Print[gradfdotf];
x1 = x0 - q*gradfdotf;
Print[x1];
q /. Solve[D[fdotf[x1[[1]], x1[[2]], x1[[3]], x1[[4]]], q] == 0, q];
Print[q];
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stackexchange Frank :) The line `q /. Solve[D[fdotf[x1[[1]], x1[[2]], x1[[3]], x1[[4]]], q] == 0, q];`inside your `For` loop takes the expression `q` and replaces it according to the replacement rule produced by `Solve`. Nowhere do you **assign** anything to `q`.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
fdotf[x_, y_, z_, w_] = 
  (4*x - 2*y + 3*z - 5*w)^2 + (3*x + 3*y + 5*z - 8*w)^2 + 
  (-6*x - 1*y + 4*z + 3*w)^2 + (-4*x + 2*y - 3*z + 5*w)^2;
x0 = {5, 5, 5, 5};
```

then the following code will do what you want.

```
Clear[q]
Do[
  Print[x0];
  gradfdotf = Grad[fdotf[x, y, z, w], {x, y, z, w}];
  gradfdotf = Simplify[gradfdotf];
  gradfdotf = 
    gradfdotf /. {x -> x0[[1]], y -> x0[[2]], z -> x0[[3]], w -> x0[[4]]};
  Print[gradfdotf];
  x1 = x0 - q*gradfdotf;
  sol =
    Solve[D[fdotf[x1[[1]], x1[[2]], x1[[3]], x1[[4]]], q] == 0, q][[1, 1]] // N;
  Print[sol];
  Print[x1 /. sol],
  4]
```

> ```
> {5, 5, 5, 5}
> {90, 90, 150, -240}
> q -> 0.00274134
> {4.75328, 4.75328, 4.5888, 5.65792}
> ...
> {5, 5, 5, 5}
> {90, 90, 150, -240}
> q -> 0.00274134
> {4.75328, 4.75328, 4.5888, 5.65792}
> ```

#### Notes

1. `Do` is easier to write than `For` and runs faster. Note not index is needed as none is referred in the code.
2. It is not necessary make an assignment to `q`, but it is necessary to substitute it into `x1`.

#### Update

The above solution to your problem works and maintains the basic structure of your code, but is far from optimal. For one thing, no loop, `For` or `Do`, seems necessary nor desirable. For another, it does seem very desirable to implement a solution where all variables are localized and which works for any input `x0` which is a vector of four numeric quantities.

Here is a such a solution.

```
gradfdotf[x_, y_, z_, w_] = Grad[fdotf[x, y, z, w], {x, y, z, w}];
solver[x0 : {Repeated[_?NumericQ, {4}]}] :=
  Module[{q, gradfdotv, x1, sol},
    Print[x0];
    gradfdotv = gradfdotf @@ x0;
    Print[gradfdotv];
    x1 = x0 - q*gradfdotv;
    sol =
     Solve[D[fdotf[x1[[1]], x1[[2]], x1[[3]], x1[[4]]], q] == 0, q][[1, 1]] // N;
    Print[sol[[2]]];
    x1 /. sol]
```

This also has the advantage that it returns the vector `x1` so it can used in further computations.

#### Examples

```
solver[ConstantArray[5, 4]]
```

> ```
> {5, 5, 5, 5}
> {90, 90, 150, -240}
> 0.00274134
> {4.75328, 4.75328, 4.5888, 5.65792}
> ```

```
solver[Range[4]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> {-416, 8, -84, 444}
> 0.00256274
> {2.0661, 1.9795, 3.21527, 2.86214}
> ```